# ¿Cómo establezco un valor especifico en CSS para un elemento con un clase de Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando darle un valor de `margin-top` distinto a un div en específico, pero este no se aplica y prioriza el de la clase row de Boostrap. Intenté aplicarlo por ID para ser más especificos de la siguiente manera

```
<div class="row" id="footer-row" >
<div class="col" >columna1</div>
<div class="col" >columna2</div>
</div>

<style>
#footer-row {
position: relative;
margin-top: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Este solamente me ha funcionado cuando aplico el estilo directamente a la etiqueta de esta manera

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 100px:" ></div>
```

Comment: Puedes usar, conjuntamente con la clase row, la clase de bootstrap `mt-5` (es la más grande, pero si necesitas menos puedes usar la 4,  3, etc...). [Referencia](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)  Si usas estilos personalizados o fijos como pretendes tu footer podria dejar de ser responsive.

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de usar id crea una clase en CSS y aplicala al div despues de la clase row

Comment: ¿Por qué funcionaría con una clase y no con un id que tiene más especificidad?

Answer (score 1):

el CSS que añade bootstrap tiene mucha prioridad debido a que usa clases. A todos los estilos que quieras aplicar sobre el de bootstrap deberías añadirle `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar aplicando `!important` al estilo:

```
<div class="row" id="footer-row" >
<div class="col" >columna1</div>
<div class="col" >columna2</div>
</div>

<style>
#footer-row {
position: relative;
/* Utilización del !important*/
margin-top: 100px !important;
}
</style>
```